# How do I use BEAST for divergence time estimation in this case?

Tags: bioinformatics, phylogenetics, speciation

I am interested in using BEAST to find the divergence time estimates of species separations within a genus of frogs. The genus separated from a outgroup taxon I have chosen around 80 million years ago. That is all the information I have. Is it possible for me to do a divergence analysis using BEAST and set an informative prior based on the information I have ?

Comment: Doesn't BEAST require molecular sequences for it to do its work?